# Is this a good use case for a Deferred?

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, es6-promise, deferred

I've often heard describing the use of `Deferred` as an 'anti-pattern' (e.g. [here](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern)).
I am trying to understand if I have a scenario where using a deferred would make sense, maybe you can help. I have a recaptcha on the page of a single page web app. To do certain actions the captcha test needs to be passed. Since the captcha expires after sometime the user might need to redo the test. But other times the user might trigger one of these actions before the captcha has expired, therefore it should not redo the test. Here below some pseudo code to better understand:

```
class App {
  constructor () {
    this.captchaPromise = new Deferred();
  }

  maybeDoIt () {
    this.captchaPromise.then(() => {
       this._doIt();
    })
  }

  _doIt () {
    alert('done');
  }

  _onCaptchaSuccess () {
    this.captchaPromise.resolve();
  }

  _onCaptchaExpire () {
    this.captchaPromise.reject();
    this.captchaPromise = new Deferred();
  }
}

const app = new App();

window._captchaOnload = function () {
  window.grecaptcha.render('js-captcha', {
    'sitekey': 'dsadaablsabllbalblablalblablablalbalbalblablabla31',
    'callback': app._onCaptchaSuccess.bind(app),
    'expired-callback': app._onCaptchaExpire.bind(app)
  });
};
```

Do you think this is a good way to implement the above scenario?

I am also kind of struggling to find a vanilla js deferred implementation or library that supports es6 module import syntax and that supports at least IE9 and up, even IE8 would be great (I cannot use jQuery). Any help is very appreciated.

## Update:

thank you for your answer, in the end I decided I don't need a promise at all. To promisify the recaptcha render was a nice idea though. I solved doing the following:

```
  _doIt (data) {
    if (!this._captchaSolved) {
      this._dataToUseAfterCaptchaSuccess = data;
      return;
    }
    this._dataToUseAfterCaptchaSuccess = null;

    console.log('done', data);
  }

  _onCaptchaSuccess (captchaResponse) {
    this._captchaSolved = true;
    this._captchaResponse = captchaResponse;

    if (this._dataToUseAfterCaptchaSuccess) {
      this._doIt(this._dataToUseAfterCaptchaSuccess);
    }
  }

  _onCaptchaExpire () {
    this._captchaSolved = false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, a Deferred is not necessary.

As written, it does two things, both of which can be achieved more simply :

- as a state indicator: 'pending' effectively means 'unexpired', and 'rejected' means 'expired'. A simple Boolean could be used instead.
- as a means of calling `_doIt()`:  which could be called directly from the `_onCaptchaSuccess` handler or even specified as .render's 'callback' handler.

A more realistic approach would be to promisify `window.grecaptcha.render()`, eg as follows :

```
window._captchaOnload = function () {
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        window.grecaptcha.render('js-captcha', {
            'sitekey': 'dsadaablsabllbalblablalblablablalbalbalblablabla31',
            'callback': resolve,
            'expired-callback': reject
        });
    })
    .then(app._doIt.bind(app), app.expire.bind(app));
};
```

`app` would need to be written accordingly, not involving Deferreds or promises.

Comment: Thank you @Roamer-1888 ! I updated my question with the solution I used